# collapsible navbar not working on mobile devices (2.3.2)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using twitter bootstrap **ver. 2.3.2** and I have just realized that my **navbar** does not work properly if rendered on a mobile device.

The problem is the **sub-items** of each top menu do not redirect to the page specified in the url.

It works has expected if I resize my browser's window on a desktop computer. 
I've tested it with an android phone (4.0.3), iPhone 4, and opera mobile emulator.

I've prepared a bootply [here](http://bootply.com/79897) which can be rendered [here](http://bootply.com/render/79897).

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href="/">&nbsp;</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a id="mnuItem_0" href="#" data-target="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">HOME<b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="mnuItem_0">
                            <li role="presentation">
                              <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                              <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="LogOff" href="/Authentication/LogOff"><i class="icon-off"></i> Exit</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a id="mnuItem_1" href="#" data-target="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">USERS<b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="mnuItem_1">
                            <li role="presentation">
                              <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Roles"><i class="icon-group"></i> Roles</a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                              <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Users"><i class="icon-user"></i> Users</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no solution to this and the bug has been introduced with version 2.3.2 (it works on  2.3.1).

**Upgraded to version 3.0.0** ... with some pains.